Getting an error for moq : Can not instantiate proxy of class
I'm writing a unit test using Moq for the first time, and I'm encountering an error related to the constructor. I'm trying to get my unit test to work, but I'm stuck at this point. Below is the full code for my unit test and error i am getting

Can not instantiate proxy of class: CCS.Data.Postgres.Command.DbCommandTransactionExecutorPostgres.
Could not find a constructor that would match given arguments:
System.String
(Parameter 'constructorArguments')'

public RateCalculationCommandRepositoryPostgresTest()
{
    var mockDbCommandTransactionExecutor = new Mock<DbCommandTransactionExecutorPostgres>("connectionString") { 
        CallBase = true 
    };
    
    _mockCommandRepositoryFactory = new Mock<ICommandRepositoryFactory>();
    _repository = new RateCalculationCommandRepositoryPostgres(
        mockDbCommandTransactionExecutor.Object,
        _mockCommandRepositoryFactory.Object
    );
} 

